# Generating of the matrix ring by two hermitian matices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $p$ be a prime and $q=p^n$. Let $\mathbb F_{q^2}$ be a field with $q^2$ elements and $\sigma$ its authomorhism of order two. A $m$ by $m$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb F_{q^2}$ is  *hermitian* if $A^\sigma$ coincides with the traspose of $A$.

Do you know a reference to the following result?

**Theorem**. The ring of $m$ by $m$ matrices over  $\mathbb F_{q^2}$ can be generated over $\mathbb F_p$ by two hermitian matrices.

Comment: When you say: "do you know a reference", are you implying that the result is known to be true?

Comment: It should be true. For any field $k$, "most" pairs $(A,B)$ of matrices generate $\mathrm{Mat}_n(k)$. Notice that the dimension of the subspace of $\mathrm{Mat}_n(k)$ spanned the monomials in $A$ and $B$ stays the same if we enlarge the field, so we may take $k$ algebraically closed. Then most $A$ will be diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues. Polynomials in $A$ then give the matrices $e_{ii}$. For most $B$, $e_{ii} B e_{jj}$ is nonzero for all pairs $(i,j)$, and then the $e_{ii} B e_{jj}$ span all matrices. (continued)

Comment: This argument is easy to make precise over an infinite field. With more work, one can also use it over a finite field. I spent some time try to make it work in the setting of this problem, where we have the Hermitian condition to deal with and have the extra complication of working both with $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$, but I ran out of energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement  is false  if  $m=2$.

For $m>2$, let $\alpha$ be a generator of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{q^2}$.  Then the   matrices  $\alpha E_{1,2}+\sigma(\alpha) E_{2,1}$ and   $\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} (E_{i,i+1}+E_{i+1,i})$ generate the ring of m by m matrices over $\mathbb F_{q^2}$.